# Parse body as object in node

Tags: json, node.js

I have the following code and I want parse the body string into an object but I have the following error

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 2

```
var http = require('http') ;

http.get('http://www.w3schools.com/' , function (resp) {
    var respContent = '' ;
    resp.on('data' , function (data) {
        respContent += data.toString() ;//data is a buffer instance
    }) ;
    resp.on('end' ,  function() {
      var profile=JSON.parse(respContent);
      console.dir(profile);
    }) ;
}).on('error' , console.error) ;
```

Comment: It is clearly saying you have something wrong in json "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 2". Console log respContent before you parse it. you will find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't use JSON.parse on XML content. It's waiting a string formatted like JSON.

```
var string = '{"test":"magie", "that":"work", "number": 1}';
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(string);
console.log(jsonObject);
```

Comment: I have the code from treehouse and there is full working but on my node is not working plus that I have toString method on content.

Comment: Why do you want to JSON.parse respContent ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.Instead of 'http' I have to use 'https'